# Problem with spacing in image source

Tags: spacing, graphics

```
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{\tiny Source:{#1}}}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{./24GHz-Radar-Kit}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./ds}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Infineon 24GHz Radar Development Kit}
    \source{ https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf-and-wireless-control/mm-wave-mmic/24-ghz-radar-automotive/channel.html?channel=5546d4624f205c9a014f465e853c277c}
    \label{radardiagram}
\end{figure}
```

Hello,

I have defined a command called 'Source' that adds an extra line below the caption of an image. My problem is that it seems to be leaving too much space between the word 'Source' and the following source link. I get the underfull hbox badness 10000 error.

Can anyone please tell me what I can do here?

Thanks in advance!

Pranav

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `measuredfigure` environment from `threeparttable`, and package `url` for a proper formatting of urls:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption, float, threeparttable}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\def\UrlFont{\sffamily}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{\footnotesize Source: {#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{measuredfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{./24GHz-Radar-Kit}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./ds}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Infineon 24\,GHz Radar Development Kit}\label{radardiagram}\medskip
    \source{\url{https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf-and-wireless-control/mm-wave-mmic/24-ghz-radar-automotive/channel.html?channel=5546d4624f205c9a014f465e853c277c}}
  \end{measuredfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]